# Best way to clean or shine a silver jewelry

Tags: home, metals, jewelry

What are some cost-effective methods to clean a silver necklace or bracelet using homemade solutions?

One method I know is to submerge a jewelry in a salt bath (1 teaspoon of table salt + strips of aluminum foil + tap water). But I am afraid that my the layer of my jewelry will peel off.

P.S. How about stainless steel jewelries, can you cite some methods.

Comment: I don't see how this requires a hack; just use silver polish.

Comment: The electrolytic method you outline is quite gentle, even on silver plate, and actually regenerates silver that would be lost to silver sulfide removed in polishing. However, electrolysis **will damage** niello (blackened silver) and composite objects (e.g. silver with a shell locket glued to it).

Comment: @Shokhet: You've clearly never tried to clean a necklace.

Comment: I use sodium bicarbonate and aluminium foil in warm water. If you stir it around a bit it works even better. This works for intricate stuff and chains, and if it's not good enough you can help it along with an old toothbrush.

Answer (score 2):

The professional way to clean jewellery is to use an ultrasonic bath.  The vibration releases the dirt particles from the smallest recesses of the jewellery.

To do this as a hack you need to replicate the vibration as best you can.

Place the jewellery in a small dish and cover it with water in which you add a small amount of washing up liquid.

This now needs to be vibrated.  Good sources of vibration about the house would include a washing machine on a spin cycle or a loudspeaker.  Obviously you need to take care that no spillage of the liquid can occur and the dish doesn't slide off onto the floor.

Leave the dish to vibrate for 15-20 minutes and rinse off the jewellery.

This should remove much of the dirt.  No scrubbing or brushing has taken place.  This works for any metal, not just silver.

Answer (score 1):

Take toothpaste and a toothbrush and clean the jewelry like you clean your teeth. I use Colgate toothpaste to clean my ring and it shines as if it were new.

Answer (score 0):

I too use toothpaste too! Preferably paste not gel! Or simply wear jewelry in the shower and soap them up with a bar of soap and rinse!this makes them sparkle like new!